# How to get multiple set of strings from a file using specific patterns?

Tags: linux

**Edited**

This is the content of example.dat file:

```
AAA*00*          *00*          *66*1234567890     *ZZ*ASD-LKJ        *170630*1933*U*00401*100000023*0*P*\~SS*IN*2035735845*JWN-DSD*20660606*0606*1023*X*DF4WE43R4RA~BIG*20660606*2771417*19990919*88146417~GE*3*1023~IEA*1*100000023~
```

The data I needed are inside a segment. A segment is separated by `~` and the data I needed is called an element. An element is separated by a `*`.

These are the pattern to find those strings:

```
Segments         Element number          Needed Data
  AAA            6th, 8th & 13th         1234567890, ASD-LKJ & 100000023
  SS             6th                     1023
  BIG            4th                     88146417
  GE             1st                     3
```

Is there a command that outputs these data?

```
100000023    1023    3    1234567890    ASD-LKJ    88146417
```

Note: In the real world, the file contains really long set of strings and many segments but the pattern of segments and the place where the elements positioned stays the same.

Comment: is the input single line or multiple line? what is the logic to extract strings? not able to see a pattern... and as `AAA` is only once in input string, how do you expect multiple output?

Comment: It's single line. Actually it's a file with a really long set of strings. I just shorten it for just an example. I'll update the patterns for everyone to understand further.

Comment: it is still not clear on what basis you need to extract data from each of these segments... and why does last segment you show has `~` in it

Comment: Please edit the whole question again and give sample input and output.

Comment: Please see my last update. I think it's understandable enough. You can edit my question if you want.

Answer (score 1):

This will output your example data in your example output format

```
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN { FS="*"; }
$1=="AAA" { printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", $7, $9, $14 }
$1=="SS"  { print $7 }
$1=="BIG" { print $5 }
$1=="GE"  { print $2 }
$ awk -f script.awk example.dat
1234567890     
ASD-LKJ        
100000023
1023
88146417
3
```

Comment: When I type "cat script.awk" it returns "cat: script.awk: No such file or directory". How to do that? Sorry I'm just new to Linux/Unix. Do you have a simpler command like 1 line just like grep?

Comment: How to write that in shell? Do I do this:
1st to type:
`[current_directory]$ cat script.awk`
2nd:
`BEGIN { FS="*"; }`
`[current_directory]$ 1=="AAA" { printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", $7, $9, $14 }`
`[current_directory]$ 1=="SS"  { print $7 }`
`[current_directory]$ 1=="BIG" { print $5 }`
`[current_directory]$ 1=="GE"  { print $2 }`
`[current_directory]$ awk -f script.awk example.dat`

But's it's not working for me. I'm doing it wrong. Kindly explain it further. I'm just new to Linux/Unix.

Comment: Use a text editor such as vi or nano to create script.awk

Comment: I tried `vi script.awk`, stored `BEGIN { FS="*"; }` up to `$1=="GE"  { print $2 }`, save it `chmod 755 script.awk` and then finally run the command `awk -f script.awk example.dat` but I only get these three output `1234567890     
ASD-LKJ        
100000023`